# Whitelisted chrome extension is blocked by Administrator

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a self hosted chrome extension.
It is ready for self update - URL in manifest file and configured GP on PC.
Extension could not be installed automatically or manually.

Tried to run browser with debug *chrome.exe --vmodule=extension_updater=2 --enable-logging --extensions-update-frequency=30* but there are no errors related to my extension, it is even not listed in log.

When i try to drug extension in dev mode to browser i have an error that my extension is disabled by admin, but it is whitelisted, blacklist section is missing.
All is ok in chrome://policy

Any ideas ?

Comment: Blacklisting is not the only [extension-related policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/#extensions) that may block installation.

Comment: Google Cloud management is not used, domain policies only. Tried different  **extension-related policy** options but no luck. What should i check more ?

Comment: Those policies I've linked aren't cloud-specific. Anyway I don't have more ideas. Maybe you can show your chrome://policy output and something comes up.

Comment: https://imgur.com/x5Q4DWK - policy output

Comment: Maybe there's a typo in the installation URL in some of the settings.

Comment: All paths are ok.

Comment: I have just increased version, one more time and extension began to be updated. Very strange. Waiting for next update. Thanks to @wOxxOm